# Fastest way to subtract known music tracks from live videogame audio stream

Tags: fourier-transform, audio, convolution, filtering, music

I want to isolate video game "action" sounds from the video game soundtrack. Given all ~20 songs, I'd like to filter them out from any live audio stream during gameplay.

What is a fast and robust way to do this?

More info: I am using this to preprocess the audio input for a neural network which is making decisions in real-time, so it needs to be fast (on the order of 100ms or less). It also needs to be robust, since the soundtrack can be interrupted in-game events or pausing the game.

I am thinking of binning the audio with small bins, taking a FFT, identifying which song is playing by feeding the spectogram to a convolutional neural network, and subtracting the song. I fear this approach would be too slow, though.

Comment: "input for a neural network" <-> "needs to be fast" why? Sounds like you want to analyze a recording ("offline analysis"), in which case you've got all the time in the world.

Comment: @MarcusMüller He stated that he would like to filter thos songs "from any __live audio stream__ during gameplay", so I think that he needs to be fast because of that: it has to be done on the fly.

Comment: @Tendero "from a live stream" is not the same as "for live streaming"; that's why I ask :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Makes sense, the OP should clarify that.

Comment: @MarcusMüller this is not for streaming. The second neural network is playing the video game in real-time and thus won't have "all the time in the world".

Comment: Sounds like cross correlations with the "known" audio sequences would give you good inputs for your neural network to train on. What kind of time requirements do you have and what type of processing power do you have at your disposal?

Comment: @hops I have two older CUDA 2.x compatible GPUs. I want the entire decision-making process (including the preprocessing step this question is about) to be on the order of human reaction time, so around 200-250 milliseconds.

Comment: Is latency a consideration? For example, can you delay the video to line up with the output of the audio so that things match up correctly? If so, I would experiment with the correlation option. CUDA cores are quite good at performing sequence correlations fairly quickly. The difficult thing will be to train well enough to avoid false positives (as they will cause odd things to happen).

Comment: @hops I could skip video frames while I wait for the audio to get the music filtered out of it.

Comment: @hops I have every known audio sequence in the game, totaling hundreds. Most are <1 sec long, and ~80% of all audio are the songs, which are  4 min+ each. Do you have any ideas for doing correlations against all the known audio sequences? Using a for loop would be very slow, so it would be great to somehow do it as a single matrix operation.

Comment: I would expect you to implement it with the CUDA cores as long as you have a sufficiently powerful GPU, this should be no problem. Of course hundreds of possible sounds is a lot, so I'm not sure this is feasible. I don't know how many cores are used by your Neural Network or how many are available for you to use total though. See pg 26 of this document for more info: http://docs.nvidia.com/pdf/CUBLAS_Library.pdf

Comment: Would you perhaps be better off using online ICA to detect the game noises instead of filtering out lots of large background sound?

Comment: @wwwslinger that's a great idea!